# Matlab adding KeyListener to existing button

Tags: matlab, keylistener

I've written a Matlab program which counts different values when are particular button is pressed (so far just the numbers of "yes" and "no"). I'm trying to add a key listener so that when I press, for example, <kbd>n</kbd> on the keyboard the button is pressed, or the same actions are completed.  I have tried the `addListener` and `keyfunclistener` functions but neither seems to be working.

Here is an example of the button:

```
no=uicontrol(h_fig,'callback',countnonerve,'position',[.65 .07 .1 .08],'string','No','style','pushbutton','Units','normalized');
```

Any suggestions? It would be very helpful I'm not familiar with MatLab

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the **KeyPressFcn** property of the figure to record/capture individual key presses:

```
function  keypress_Test
   h = figure;
   set(h,'KeyPressFcn',@keyPressCb);

   function keyPressCb(src,evnt)
        disp(['key pressed: ' evnt.Key]);
   end
end
```

The above code can be pasted into a file and saved as **keypress_Test.m**.  A figure is created and a callback assigned to the **KeyPressFcn** property.

It can be easily adapted for your GUI.  Wherever you have access to the figure handles (probably the **h_fig** from above) just add `set(h_fig,'KeyPressFcn',@keyPressCb);` and paste the **keyPressCb** code into the same file.

If you are counting the number of times a certain key is pressed, then you will have to save this information somewhere..probably to the **handles** structure.  Is that the case?  If so, then you can easily access this from the callback

```
function keyPressCb(src,evnt)
    disp(['key pressed: ' evnt.Key]);

    % get the handles structure
    handles = guidata(src);

    if ~isempty(handles)
       % do something here - increment count for evnt.Key

       % save the updated count
       guidata(src,handles);

    end
end
```

Try it out and see what happens!

Comment: Hey Geoff, I have buttons now that already do all the counting/saving of data.  The thing is they are pressed very frequently and it would be easier to use a keypress instead.  I would like pressing 'n' to press the No button and the 'y' key the press the Yes button (or call the same function that the buttons does). To do this can I just use the same 'callback' function as the button?  I tried the method above but could not get it to work

Comment: I'm guessing you have two callbacks - one for the No button and one for the Yes.  You could try to invoke either callback depending upon the key by adding the following if (and elseif) to the above `KeyPressCb`: `if strcmpi(evnt.Character,'n'); % call no callback`. That may work.  Although it might be better to separate the logic from the no and yes button callbacks into their own separate functions that can be called from either the button callbacks or from the key press one.  These separate functions would have the code that is common to either pushing the No button OR pushing the 'n' key.

Comment: I keep getting this error: " Undefined function 'keyPressCb' for input arguments of type 'struct'. "

Comment: What does your code look like now?  Have you defined the `keyPressCb` as a function within your file?